# Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate defintitions for one or more documents

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

Trying to create a blog / website with **GatsbyJS** and I'm not sure why I keep getting this error:

> GraphQL Error There was an error while compiling your site's GraphQL
>   queries.   Error: RelayParser: Encountered duplicate defintitions for
>   one or more documents: each document must have a unique name.
>   Duplicated documents:
>   - eDocumentsGitHubChildishhalbinoGithubIoSrcComponentsBlogBlogPostTemplateBlogPostTemplateJs3803534083

I've tried moving files / folders around, changing queries, etc. Not even sure where to start really.

https://github.com/ChildishhAlbino/childishhalbino.github.io/tree/problem-fixing

A repository with the code on it. Too many documents to paste code from so I hope you don't mind me doing it this way.

- Page should load without errors.
- There should be 3 blog posts with the content from the /posts/ markdown files.
- The 'about' tab should display 3 'cards' each with information from the /bio/ markdown files.
- The blurb should load with information from the 'blurb.md' file.

Please feel free to ask questions if I haven't explained something correctly.

Comment: Did you solve this? I came across this issue today.

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11688

Comment: It should be fixed now, but it was a bug in Gatsby. Check the casing of your path to your template file.